# Processor Architecture mismatch - Visual Studio, Nuget, Stylecop

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, stylecop, cpu-architecture

I am using Visual Studio for a C# application. I have a 64-bit machine. I installed the latest version of Nuget, and Stylecop. When I build, I get warnings as

```
There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
being built "MSIL" and the processor architecture of the reference
NuGet.VisualStudio", "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please 
consider changing the targeted processor architecture of your project 
through the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
between your project and references, or take a dependency on references with
a processor architecture that matches the targeted processor architecture of
your project."
```

Any idea what this is please?

Answer (score 1):

I have two working solutions for this problem :
1st change the target framework from Project > Properties > Build tab > Platform target to x64 
If the above solution does not work in most cases then try with another which worked every time for me.
Go to Project Source code folder > obj > x64 > Debug and delete all the files there
Now try to publish your solution from Visual Studio and it will work.
Some screenshots to understand this better

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]
   4.[image]
   5.[image]
   6.[image]

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out - I went to the configuration manager, and set the the platform for teh project as x64. Did the trick!